# Similar expression to "Coalesce" in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

What is the similar query to below code in entity framework c#.

```
SELECT StudentId,Coalesce(s.FName + ' ' + s.MName + ' ' + s.LName,
    s.FName + ' ' + s.MName,
    s.FName) AS FullName
FROM Student s
WHERE s.StudentId = 'S101';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

e.g.

```
string text1 = null;
string result = text1 == null ? "default" : text1 ;
```

you can do

```
string result = text1 ?? "default";
```

Comment: Using the null-coalescing operator works when writing queries in EF Core. e.g. writing the following in an EF query: "where (s.FName + ' ' + s.MName + ' ' + s.LName) ?? (s.FName + ' ' + s.MName) ?? s.FName)" will be translated by EF into the coalesce statement COALESCE(s.FName + ' ' + s.MName + ' ' + s.LName, s.FName + ' ' + s.MName, s.FName)

Answer (score -2):

let's say i want to check amount as coalesce then use *Nullable* as mention in below code sample

```
context.Order.Where(w => w.Status == "paid").Sum(s => (Nullable<int>) s.Amount ?? 0)
```